# Installing apache , php and mysql on ubuntu 8

Tags: installation, apache2, mysql, php

I want to install php, mysql and apache on my ubuntu ,
I tried all tasks but I can not do it.
there is no package php, apache or mysql
please help me

Comment: what are the steps u did for installing apache,php........

Comment: From commandline: `tasksel`. It will show a list including LAMP server install.

Comment: "I tried all tasks" is very vague. Please tell us *what you actually tried* and also *what happened*.

Answer (score 7):

8.04 still has server support until next year (2013-04) so if you're using Ubuntu server, it should be as simple as this:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-server php5 php-pear php5-suhosin php5-mysql
```

Hardy (8.04) is just months away from being end-of-life so there are a few implications:

- Some package mirrors may have closed down. The desktop support ended in 2011 so mirrors may have started cleaning things up too eagerly. If you're having problems (packages or lists not available), you may need to switch to another.
- Things are pretty old. "Support" for an application is essentially a promise that security updates will be backported but it's not a guarantee for anything else. You may be missing out on newer features in the software stack.
- This will be dead in under six months. Consider the effort you're putting in here and wonder if that would not be better spent just installing 12.04. That will give you until 2017 before you need to consider upgrading.

#### The most important thing is you *don't leave it rotting*.

Outdated, unupdated software is the main reason why the internet has as many problems as it does. If all the XP users in the world applied their security updates when they were released, there wouldn't be anywhere near as much spam or as many viruses circulating around the web.

Linux servers are no different. If you leave an ancient, insecure version of PHP croaking around on the internet, somebody will find it and will exploit it. Before you know it, it'll be serving up phishing websites and hosting malware. Don't let it go this far.

Comment: from what i've  heard from the Server Team people, the packages aren't updated unless there's High/Critical bugs.  As far as I can tell, there're apache security bugs needing fixing in hardy that still aren't fixed and have been there for months if not years.  It's still not advised to use 8.04.  Even the server team is recommending use at least 10.04.